# Division of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Theorem:

?For $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $p$ prime if $\exists a\in \mathbb{Z} : f(a)\equiv 0\pmod p $ then $f(x)\equiv f_1(x)(x-a)\pmod p$ for some $f_1\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$

The proof is simple argument of division of polynomials with a remainder. However, I don't undestand why it does not work for p not prime. May I ask for help?

Comment: The proof works perfectly well for every integer $p$. More generally, over any commutative ring, you can divide-with-remainder any polynomial by any **monic** polynomial.

Comment: Ok, I guess I trusted my notes too much

Comment: The notes aren't being wrong -- they are just not as general as they could be.

Comment: @darijgrinberg In my notes it is said that it does not work for p not prime. Anyway, thanks for reply.

Comment: @MattSamuel $x^2=(x+3)(x-3)+9 => x^2\equiv(x+3)(x-3)$

Comment: See, the disclaimer was not for naught!